# jquery - click event binding and launching on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Happy Friday errybody!

Alright, so I'm having trouble binding a 'click' event when a particular class of divs load.

What happens is that the 'click' event is being triggered on load.  I've even tried unbinding before I bind.

```
onAppLoad = function() {
  console.log('span 4 loaded');

  hovering = function() {
    console.log('hovering!');
  }

  $.each($('.span4 > a'), function() {
    var whichApp = $(this).attr('data-content');

    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).bind('click', hovering());

  })   
}

$('.span4').load(onAppLoad());
```

Comment: Could you provide a live example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
 $(this).bind('click', hovering());
```

Here you are calling the function `hovering` while what you want it to give the reference. Try this :

```
 $(this).bind('click', hovering);
```

Your `.load()` is wrong too (for the same reason).

```
$('.span4').load(onAppLoad);
```

Side note about the `.each`. When you are iterating a jquery object, you should write it like that :

```
$('.span4 > a').each(function() {})
```

Comment: Ahh... your advice on referencing vs calling worked.  Also switched around my .each like you recommended.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I see i your code:
1. You're missing a closing bracket for `onAppLoad()`
2. Change `$(this).bind('click', hovering());` to `$(this).bind('click', hovering);`
3. Change `$('.span4').load(onAppLoad());` to `$('.span4').load(onAppLoad);`

Out of curiosity, why not put all event handlers in a `$(document).ready()` event?

Comment: I don't want to put the event on handlers on .ready() because the spans are being written by php.

Comment: How is that relevant? They are rendered by the browser on the client side, not by PHP on the sever side.

Comment: At first I theorized that the spans were not going to be loaded on the DOM on .ready() -- which is why I didn't want to bind them at that time.  But I switched it to bind on ready and it's working fine!